# Find n smallest values in a list of tensors

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I am trying to find the indices of the n smallest values in a list of tensors in pytorch. Since these tensors might contain many non-unique values, I cannot simply compute percentiles to obtain the indices. The ordering of non-unique values does not matter however.

I came up with the following solution but am wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it:

```py
import torch

n = 10

tensor_list = [torch.randn(10, 10), torch.zeros(20, 20), torch.ones(30, 10)]
all_sorted, all_sorted_idx = torch.sort(torch.cat([t.view(-1) for t in tensor_list]))

cum_num_elements = torch.cumsum(torch.tensor([t.numel() for t in tensor_list]), dim=0)
cum_num_elements = torch.cat([torch.tensor([0]), cum_num_elements])

split_indeces_lt = [all_sorted_idx[:n] < cum_num_elements[i + 1] for i, _ in enumerate(cum_num_elements[1:])]
split_indeces_ge = [all_sorted_idx[:n] >= cum_num_elements[i] for i, _ in enumerate(cum_num_elements[:-1])]
split_indeces = [all_sorted_idx[:n][torch.logical_and(lt, ge)] - c for lt, ge, c in zip(split_indeces_lt, split_indeces_ge, cum_num_elements[:-1])]

n_smallest = [t.view(-1)[idx] for t, idx in zip(tensor_list, split_indeces)]
```

Ideally a solution would pick a random subset of the non-unique values instead of picking the entries of the first tensor of the list.

Comment: Hello, I don't really understand your edit. You want the n smallest values of the tensor that is produced by concatenating the whole tensor list, is that it ? Do you mean that you would prefer not to get the first occurrence of the min values, but a random occurrence ?

Comment: @trialNerror Yes exactly. In cases where the ordering is not deterministic due to multiple identical values, I want a random ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Pytorch does provide a more elegant (I think) way to do it, with `torch.unique_consecutive` (see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique_consecutive.html#torch.unique_consecutive))

I'm going to work on a tensor, not a list of tensors because as you did yourself, there's just a `cat` to do. Unraveling the indices afterward is not hard either.

```py
# We want to find the n=3 min values and positions in t 
n = 3
t = torch.tensor([1,2,3,2,0,1,4,3,2])

# To get a random occurrence, we create a random permutation
randomizer = torch.randperm(len(t))

# first, we sort t, and get the indices
sorted_t, idx_t = t[randomizer].sort()

# small util function to extract only the n smallest values and positions
head = lambda v,w : (v[:n], w[:n])

# use unique_consecutive to remove duplicates
uniques_t, counts_t = head(*torch.unique_consecutive(sorted_t, return_counts=True))

# counts_t.cumsum gives us the position of the unique values in sorted_t
uniq_idx_t = torch.cat([torch.tensor([0]), counts_t.cumsum(0)[:-1]], 0)

# And now, we have the positions of uniques_t values in t : 
final_idx_t = randomizer[idx_t[uniq_idx_t]]
print(uniques_t, final_idx_t)

#>>> tensor([0,1,2]), tensor([4,0,1])
#>>> tensor([0,1,2]), tensor([4,5,8])
#>>> tensor([0,1,2]), tensor([4,0,8])
```

EDIT : I think the added permutation solves your need-random-occurrence problem

Comment: This is a nice way of finding the n smallest unique values, thanks! Unfortunately, this does not answer my question as I was asking for the n smallest values given many identical (non-unique) values that do not allow for a strictly monotonic ordering but should nevertheless be included.

Comment: @smonsays I could not find a reliably non-deterministic sort in pytorch, so I added a permutation beforehand. Does that work for you ?